# String.Format in Database.SQLQuery command and SQL Injection

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-injection

I have to follow rule that stored procedure has to be executed in "parameterized way". I believe that its about SQL Injection protection. 
I want to know if following code can be considered as "parameterized execution" and is SQL Injection protected.

```
return Database.SqlQuery<Program>(
              String.Format("usp_GetPrograms {0},{1},{2},{3}", 
                              pID, pDisplayStart, pDisplayLength, pSearchString)
    ).ToList();
```

Otherway i can rewrite it to something like that

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<myEntityType>(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```

Iam asking because the program is complete and tested and ready to production and i dont want to rewrite the code and risk that something will broke.

What do you think about these two approaches ?

**Additional question:**
Is SqlParameter() necessary according to

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907

"Loading entities from stored procedures" section ?

**Additional question2:**
How can i pass Nullable parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First attempt you've show has nothing to do with parameterized queries. It is simply concatenated query, and it is defenseless against sql injection.

You have to use second approach you've shown if you really care about sql injection.

Comment: additional question is, can i send somehow null or default to the SqlParameter() function ?

Comment: @Muflix you can use `DBNull.Value` to pass null into stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you Andy, but how can i insert DBNull.Value into existing parameter which is for example string ?

Comment: I tried ? operator but it does not work :/ new SqlParameter("p1", ( ID == null ? ID : DBNull.Value))

Comment: @Muflix you can't use `?:` operator in this case since it is returning objects of different types from conditional branches. But you can use `??` operator in this case. Something like `new SqlParameter("p1", (object)ID ?? DBNull.Value)`

Comment: I realized another problem, how can i pass DEFAULT value ? Even if Default value is NULL, DBNull.Value send N'' Value and that failed.